# How to upload a team roster from a website or file in C?

Tags: c

I am writing my final project for my programming class. Basically I am trying to write a "Fantasy Hockey" program that will allow the user to enter the number of teams, team names, and then simulate a draft based on NHL players. The program should simulate a draft. Each team will be drafted the following:

```
2 Centers
2 Left Wingers
2 Right Wingers
4 Defensemen
2 Goalies
4 Benched Players

Total: 16 Players per team.
```

What I need help with is getting the program to pull the rosters of each team in the NHL. I tried using arrays and functions to store each team manually, but I feel like there is an easier way? Perhaps there is a way I can pull the roster from a website or a file I store them in? Like an excel file?

Here is how I'm currently storing them:

```
void detroitRedWings() {

char *detRedWingsNames[] =

//Player Names
{"Justin Abdelkader", "Joakim Andersson", "Daniel Cleary", "Pavel Datsyuk", "Danny DeKyser", "Jonathan Ericsson", "Johan Franzen", "Luke Glendening", "Jonas Gustavsson", "Darren Helm", "Jimmy Howard", "Tomas Jurco", "Jakub Kindl", "Niklas Kronwall", "Brian Lashoff", "Drew Miller", "Petr Mrazek", "Gustav Nyquist", "Kyle Quincey","Stephen Weiss", "Henrik Zetterberg", "\0"};

char *detRedWingsNumbers[] =

//Player Numbers
{"8", "18", "17", "13", "65", "52", "93", "41", "50", "43", "35", "26", "4", "55", "23", "20", "34", "14", "27","15", "2", "21", "90", "40", "\0"};
char *detRedWingsPOS[] =

//Player Positions
{"LW", "C", "RW", "C/LW", "D", "D", "RW", "C", "G", "C", "G", "RW", "D", "D", "D", "LW", "G", "RW", "D", "C", "D", "LW", "C", "C", "\0"};

}
```

There must be an easier way to store 30 teams!! If so, can anyone please help me do this?

I have been using this website: http://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/DET/2015.html

To fill in the arrays, wouldn't there be a way for the program itself to pull the roster and store it in an array?

Comment: Okay, are you using C, C++ or C#? These are completely different.

Comment: I'm using C. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: So you tagged your question C# and C++ because...? It's also worth noting that variable length arrays like this are traditionally terminated with `NULL` and not a null byte in a string, something that doesn't even make sense in C as they're already NULL terminated.

Comment: do you know what a `struct` is? that would be a good place to start.

Comment: This was a question from last year.. Thanks for the response but you're a lot too late.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) requests to fetch programatically some web pages from a C program, you'll need a C HTTP client library. Conversely, if you want your C program to act as some specialized web server, you need a C HTTP server library.

I recommend:

- [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) as a good HTTP client library usable in C
- [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) as a good HTTP server library usable in C